# How does a "line" work in $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, complex-numbers

A line $\ell$ through the points $O$ and $P$ can be defined as

$$
\ell = \{r: r(0) = O + (P - O)t\}
$$

Then, $r(0) = O$ and $r(1) = P$.

Given the parameterization above, the intersection of two lines $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ and be found by solving the system of equations

$$
O_1 - O_2 = (P_2 - O_2) t_2 - (P_1 - O_1) t_1
$$

and substituting one of the $t$:s into the corresponding equation.

Now assume that $O$ and $P$ is in $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus\mathbb{R}^2$. The system of equations still has one unique solution (assuming it is not singular), but $t_1$ and $t_2$ is almost certainly not real. However, the parameter goes through two real points in the complex plane, namely $0 + 0i$, and $1 + 0i$, which implies that $t$ must follow some non-linear path. How does this work? Even more strange is that $t$ itself is some kind of two-dimensional object, with defined scalar-like multiplication and division. How to interpret that?

Comment: How do you interpret the complex line in $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note carefully the distinction between *non-real point coordinates* and *non-real parameter values*.

If $O$ and $P$ are points of $\mathbf{C}^{2}\setminus\mathbf{R}^{2}$, then $O + t(P - O)$ is not in $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ for $t = 0$ or for $t = 1$, and generally not for any *complex* $t$.

For example, if $O = (i, 0)$ and $P = (0, i)$, then
$$
O + t(P - O) = (i - ti, ti)
$$
is in $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ if and only if $i - ti$ and $ti$ are both real (which is to say, not for any complex $t$).

Separately, if it matters, a *complex line* is a real $2$-plane, but a very special type. A single non-zero vector uniquely determines a complex line through the origin, but it takes two vectors, neither a real multiple of the other, to determine a real plane. Loosely, "most" real planes in $\mathbf{C}^{2}$ are not complex lines.